# Make magento 2 grid date column follow config timezone

Tags: magento2, grid, timezone

I already set my timezone config to GMT+7 in backend , and i've created a custom module which will show grid in backend that has date column, the problem is the date is being save in utc format, and i need to show it in GMT+7 format through grid:

```
    <column name="created_at">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Created at</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

Comment: check [this](https://webkul.com/blog/save-and-get-date-time-according-to-time-zone-in-magento2/) link

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add class in date filed to format date according to time format.
use this code.

```
 <column name="creation_time" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created at</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

it should work because in class `Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date` `prepareDataSource()` it is converting date.

```
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
{
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
            if (isset($item[$this->getData('name')])) {
                $date = $this->timezone->date(new \DateTime($item[$this->getData('name')]));
                $timezone = isset($this->getConfiguration()['timezone'])
                    ? $this->booleanUtils->convert($this->getConfiguration()['timezone'])
                    : true;
                if (!$timezone) {
                    $date = new \DateTime($item[$this->getData('name')]);
                }
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            }
        }
    }

    return $dataSource;
}
```